# WSO2APM 4.2 Docker image can't start the /publisher

Tags: tomcat, wso2-api-manager, catalina

When start the Docker image for WSO2 APIM 4.2 With analytics /publisher can't start error in log is:

ERROR - ContextLoader Context initialization failed
....
...
ERROR - [/api/am/publisher] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'AuthenticationInterceptor' while setting bean property 'inInterceptors' with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIManagerConfiguration.getJwtConfigurationDto()" because "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.common.APIMConfigUtil.configuration" is null

Any idea where to start to solve this null issue?

WSO2 APIM 4.2 container to open /publisher normal

Comment: settings.json file define the value well    "app": {
        "context": "/publisher",
        "customUrl": {
            "enabled": false,
            "forwardedHeader": "X-Forwarded-For"
        },